# reading json to pandas DataFrame but with thousands of rows to pandas append

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas

I have an text file, where each line I have cleansed up to be of a json format. I can read each line, clean them, and convert them into a panda dataframe.

My problem is that I want to add/combine them all into one dataframe, but there are more than 200k lines.

I am reading each line in as 'd' = `'{"test1":"test2","data":{"key":{"isin":"test3"},"creationTimeStamp":1541491884194,"signal":0,"hPreds":[0,0,0,0],"bidPrice":6.413000,"preferredBidSize":1,"offerPrice":6.415000,"preferredOfferSize":1,"averageTradeSize":1029,"averageTradePrice":0.065252,"changedValues":true,"test4":10,"snapshot":false}}'`

Assume I am able to convert each line into a panda... is there a way to append each line into the panda dataframe, such that it is very fast. Right now, with >200k lines, it takes hours to append... reading the file itself takes less than 5 min...

```
file ='fileName.txt'
with open(file) as f:
    content = f.readlines()
content = [x.strip() for x in content]

data = pd.DataFrame()
count = 0
for line in content:
    line = line.replace('{"string1','')
    z = line.splitlines()
    z[0] = z[0][:-1]
    z = pd.read_json('[%s]' % ','.join(z))

    data = data.append(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may check with `Series`

```
pd.Series(d)
Out[154]: 
averageTradePrice              0.065
averageTradeSize                 109
bidPrice                        6.13
changedValues                   True
creationTimeStamp           15414994
Preds                   [0, 0, 0, 0]
key                  {'epic': 'XXX'}
dataLevel                         10
offerPrice                     3.333
dtype: object
```

`Preds` and `key`'s value are `list` and `dict` , that is why when you pass it to `DataFrame` it flag as  :

> ValueError: arrays must all be same length

---

Since you mention `json`

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
json_normalize(d)
Out[157]: 
          Preds  averageTradePrice     ...      key.epic  offerPrice
0  [0, 0, 0, 0]              0.065     ...           XXX       3.333
[1 rows x 9 columns]
```

Comment: thanks @W-B. I tried your solutions, and while it worked for the testing text-string I provided... unfortunately, it didn't seem to work for the (very long) actual text string I really do pull-in.

Comment: to put some context, my file f is actually a text file of > 250k rows, and I am trying to read each line, convert each line into a pandaFrame, and then append it... I had some original code using pd.read_json(...); but it no longer works...

Comment: @Kiann did you try json_normalize

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/7964527/w-b; yes I did try json_normalize.. error message : AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'